# Host or OS dependent settings in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to have different settings.json files dependent on the host or OS you are on, preferably in a layer above the user settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no current way to achieve this within the product, but it is on their backlog. You can follow the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8962) and give a thumbs up to it to show the team that it is important to you.

Answer (score 6):

The general case of adding OS and/or platform dependent settings is now tracked in VS Code [issue #5595](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5595). It appears as it is something they are interested in implementing but still working on.

Comment: It now has 927 upvotes. Still no progress on it, despite almost 8 years having passed. Go give it some more upvotes, people. And, consider working on it yourself and opening a PR if you have some time.

Answer (score 4):

[Settings Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_settings-profiles) is one of the ways you can have OS-specific profiles.

Settings Profiles is ready for preview in the **June 2022 version 1.70 Insiders** via `workbench.experimental.settingsProfiles.enabled` setting.

Discussion for this was initiated in the [#116740](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116740).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but might be helpful to some:

My issue was caused by using settings sync. I had a setting that took a command as a value, but that command has to be different on each OS. I found that disabling the 'Sync This Setting' for the particular setting solved my issue.

[image: Sync This Setting]

In my case, this added the line to `settings.json`:

```
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": ["jest.jestCommandLine"]
```

For context: [Cross platform alternative to jest.jestCommandLine for fnm users](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/1059)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
string machine = Environment.MachineName.Split('.')[0];
string filename = "config." + machine + ".json";
var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(filename);
```

So I have config.mac.json and config.pc.json
Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I would rather make symbolic links instead: `ln -s .vscode/settings.mac.json .vscode/settings.json`